# Was Sammy Jankis a Real Person or an Alter Ego of Leonard in "Memento"?

Tags: plot-explanation, character, memento

In Christopher Nolan's *Memento*, the character of Sammy Jankis plays a crucial role in understanding Leonard Shelby's condition and motivations. However, the film presents a complex narrative structure that leaves certain elements open to interpretation, particularly regarding the true existence of Sammy.

Throughout the film, Leonard narrates the story of Sammy Jankis, a man with anterograde amnesia, which seems to parallel Leonard's own condition. As the story unfolds, there are hints that suggest Sammy's story might be a concocted memory or an alter ego of Leonard himself rather than a separate individual.

Was Sammy Jankis an actual person in the context of the film, or was he a figment of Leonard's fractured memory, serving as a coping mechanism for his own guilt and trauma?

Comment: See https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/36510/how-did-leonard-manage-to-distort-his-memory-of-sammy-jankis?rq=1 & https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/3234/what-really-happened-in-memento?rq=1 - basically, he was real, but not the person we see displayed for most of the story; some parts are Jankis, some are actually Shalby.